# Looking for a pseudo-random shuffled classic Android Klondike solitaire game

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-games

Hypothesis: Most classic Android Klondike solitaire apps are "rigged" to allow the player to win more often than they would if they were playing from a pseudo-random shuffled deck.

Opinion: This is done to maintain interest in the particular app; vis-à-vis, the possible frustration of frequently losing.

Request: Can anyone recommend a classic Android Klondike solitaire app such that the shuffle is pseudo-random?

Thanks!

Joe

Comment: What if you are simply good? :-)

Comment: There are a [number of open source solitaire card apps](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=card+game&lang=en) where any "rigging" should be easily identified in code or at worst ask the respective owners/maintainers.

Comment: PeterH, Thanks for the kind words. The difference between my performance when playing with a well-shuffled deck of cards and when playing electronic solitaire is significant. Not necessarily an order of magnitude different, but likely 4X or 5X.

Comment: Morrison, the last time I read, wrote or modified code of any sort was in the mid- to late-80's. Maybe I should look under the hood of some open source solitaire apps for laughs and giggles. Unfortunately, all of the 7 or 8 inquiries I made went unanswered.